# Opening and saving multiple .xml files as .html

Tags: html, xml

I have this problem, but no idea on how to address it as I am a complete noob when it comes to automating anything on Windows.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/.../base/uccw.xml
http://www.mywebsite.com/.../base/uccx.xml
http://www.mywebsite.com/.../base/13yaf.xml
```

And I have over 300 .xml files!

I wish to view them all offline so I wish to convert them to .html.
I can download then open the individual file in browser and right click, "Save As" .html. However, I have to rename each file to the name of the xml file.

So for instance, if I open up uccw.xml and save as, it wants the name of the html file to be the name of the tab and not the name of the xml file. I want this string to be preserved - so I should be able to save it as uccw.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the aim of renaming them? You want just to view them? Maybe easier way would be click on .xml file and choose 'open with...' select right webbrowser and save it for all .xml files?

Comment: It's just something to make identifying which file is which easier. Some of the .xml files all have the same name, so they get saved with the same name, but what is unique is the filename.

Comment: Also, there are images that the xml files fetch from another site. By saving as .html I'll have a local copy of those images whereas just saving and opening the .xml will get me no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have all of them (300 files) saved on your disc in one folder? Then here is cmd command for changing the names for all files in current directory:

```
for /R %x in (*.xml) do ren "%x" *.html
```

Worked for me. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you - I got hold of all the .xml files and just renamed everything!